# Can disableKeyguard() method dismiss secure lock also?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I want to ask about the disableKeyguard() method in KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock class

The documentation says :

> Disable the keyguard from showing. If the keyguard is currently
>   showing, hide it. The keyguard will be prevented from showing again
>   until reenableKeyguard() is called. Note: This call has no effect
>   while any DevicePolicyManager is enabled that requires a password.

However this class is deprecated since API level 13

Alternate method is to use flags from Window manager
FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD and/or FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Now these flags work only if lock mode is Swipe
In case of secure lock like PIN or password it can mostly bring one window above 
lock screen, but as soon as user moves to another window, the lock reappears.

I want to ask that is the same true for disableKeyGuard() too.
Is it only effective in case of Swipe but not for secure locks like PIN / Password / Face detection etc.